# Can you factory reset an Android device but not wipe away info on the SD card?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sd-card, factory-reset

I am looking into factory resetting my 2.2 Android tablet. Is there a way to do this without wiping the contents of the SD card?

Comment: If you remove the SD card, it will surely leave it untouched :D For more details, just click the "factory-reset" tag below your question -- or follow [this link](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[factory-reset]+card) to 28 relevant answers.

Comment: Also back up your data prior to wiping, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Factory resets do not normally affect the *external* SD card, e.g., `/sdcard/external_sd`.  Some devices will wipe everything else under `/sdcard` (like the ASUS Transformer) while others will not (like the Samsung Galaxy S).  So it depends on your device and which "SD card" you're referring to, and also the filesystem layout — some devices will mount internal/external SD storage in different places than what I mentioned above.